# Unable to read a parquet file

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, pyarrow, fastparquet

I am breaking my head over this right now. I am new to this `parquet` files, and I am running into a LOT of issues with it.

I am thrown an error that reads `OSError: Passed non-file path: \datasets\proj\train\train.parquet` each time I try to create a `df` from it.

I've tried this:
 `pq.read_pandas(r'E:\datasets\proj\train\train.parquet').to_pandas()`
AND 
`od = pd.read_parquet(r'E:\datasets\proj\train\train.parquet', engine='pyarrow')`

I also changed the drive letter of the drive the dataset resides, and it's the SAME THING!

It's the same with all engines.

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Which OS are you on?

Comment: Window 2019 server.

Comment: have you tried `import os`; `os.path.exists(x)` where x is the file you're trying to load?

Comment: No. I haven't tried that. Lemme do that. I'm not at a computer ATM, so it'd be some time before I can do it.

Answer (score 10):

This might be a problem with Arrow's file path handling. You could instead pass in an already opened file:

```
import pandas as pd

with open(r'E:\datasets\proj\train\train.parquet', 'rb') as f:
    df = pd.read_parquet(f, engine='pyarrow')
```

Comment: Indeed. I had the same problem, your solution fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using fastparquet as engine, worked for me.

```
engine = "fastparquet"
```